# register server wide javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter on JBoss EAP 7

Tags: jax-rs, jboss-eap-7

Is it possible to register a `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter` server wide on JBoss EAP 7? I would like to intercept all outbound JAX-RS calls to dynamically add some context information in HTTP headers.

For JAX-WS calls I was able to do this with https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/#jax_ws_handler_chains. I can't find any documentation on a similar mechanism for JAX-RS.

Or alternatively, is there maybe another way to intercept outbound HTTP calls in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it by creating a module with the following contents:

```
package be.fgov.kszbcss.tracer.jaxrs;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;

public class TracerResteasyClientBuilder extends ResteasyClientBuilder {
    @Override
    public ResteasyClient build() {
        return super.build().register(TracerJaxRsClientRequestFilter.class);
    }
}
```

/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder

```
be.fgov.kszbcss.tracer.jaxrs.TracerResteasyClientBuilder
```

And registering it as a global module on JBoss EAP.

Answer (score 0):

For a per server solution, according to [Using HttpHandler class in Undertow](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271146) "you need to package your handler(s) into a module, and configure custom-filter in undertow subsystem."

The module.xml example and undertow configuration has been given as well as filter source code!

**Update**
There's an example of using the HTTPExchange [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange&method=endExchange) though I dont really care much for that site.  SO also has this slightly related example - it does look like it can work similarly to the JAX-WS Handlers/Interceptor [How to properly read post request body in a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203748/how-to-properly-read-post-request-body-in-a-handler)

Another good example [file upload using httphandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732110/file-upload-using-httphandler) I know they're different that dealing with JAX-RS but still may apply.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the Undertow HttpHandlers can only be used to intercept inbound requests sent TO server, and not outbound requests sent BY applications running on the server?

Comment: No, I may be completely wrong ;-) but this sounds promising "The root handler is then executed via io.undertow.server.HttpHandlers#executeRootHandler . Handlers are chained together, and each handler can modify the exchange, send a response, or delegate to a different handler. At this point there are a few different things that can happen: The exchange can be finished."  I was also thinking it was similar to the JAX-WS Handlers in that you can alter the request and/or response as its going through the chain

Comment: And based on this [HTTPHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/HttpHandler.java) using [HttpServerExchange](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.0.14.Final/undertow-core-1.0.14.Final-javadoc.jar-unzip/io/undertow/server/HttpServerExchange.html) it *looks* like you can access just about everything down to the output stream and headers

Comment: I don't need to intercept the "server" exchange though. The undertow HTTPHandler allows for intercepting inbound requests and outbound responses. I need to intercept outbound request sent by the server.

The RESTEasy JAX-RS client uses Apache HTTP Client, which uses the java.net.Socket API underneath. Undertow is not involved.

Comment: Damn, oh well, I tried!  If you find out the solution be sure to answer your question!  Good Luck!